# Can't get keyboard to load onCreate()

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

My aim is to get the keyboard to open as soon as the app is loaded. Using this code,

```
InputMethodManager inputMgr = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                  inputMgr.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);`
```

on a button, I can get the keyboard to load when the button is pressed. However, when placed in the override onCreate() section, nothing happens.

Comment: Check whether your physical keyboard is open. If so, then the softkeyboard might not pop up even if you set focus on the text field

Comment: I have a HTC Desire, so there is no physical keyboard.

Comment: Check my answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39593324/cannot-resolve-symbol-showsoftinput/39593871#39593871

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following line to the activity in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```