# Cannot resolve symbol showsoftinput

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-input-method

I'm trying to force the numeric keypad to show when my activity and EditText load. It seems there's a pretty straightforward answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105354/how-to-show-soft-keyboard-when-edittext-is-focused) and elsewhere: you say

```
EditText yourEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Fine then. So I do this and I include the imports:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
```

But when we get to showSoftInput, Studio goes red and says "Cannot resolve symbol showSoftInput". Shouldn't it be getting that symbol when I import the InputMethodManager? showSoftInput [doesn't seem to be deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html) or anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keyboard is not opening because it needs some delay ,

Follow this code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editText;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
       /* */

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            editText.requestFocus();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
        }
    },100);
    }
}
```

and XML

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="">

    <requestFocus></requestFocus>
</EditText>
```